# How to code two-way duplex streams in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream, duplex

In the latest few versions of NodeJS (v0.10.X as of writing), the Streams API has undergone a welcome redesign and I would like to start using it now.

I want to wrap both the input *and* output of a socket with an object which implements a protocol.

The so-called Duplex interface, seems to just be any stream which is readable and writable (like a socket).

It is not clear whether Duplexes should be like A or B, or whether it doesn't matter.

```
   +---+        +---+
-->| A |-->     |   |-->
   +---+        | B |
                |   |<--
                +---+
```

What is the correct code-structure/interface for an object which has two writeables and two readables?

```
+--------+   +----------+   +----
|       r|-->|w        r|-->|w    
| socket |   | protocol |   | rest of app
|       w|<--|r        w|<--|r    
+--------+   +----------+   +----
```

The problem with the diagram above is that the `protocol` object needs two separate `read` methods and two `write` methods.

Off the top of my head, I could make the protocol produce 'left' and 'right' duplex objects, or 'in' and 'out' duplex objects (to slice it a different way).

Are either of these the preferred way, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
          |      app      |
          +---------------+
              ^       |
              |       V      
           +-----+ +-----+
           |     | |     |
+----------|     |-|     |-+
| protocol | .up | |.down| |
+----------|     |-|     |-+
           |     | |     |
           +-----+ +-----+
              ^       |
              |       V
          +---------------+
          |     socket    |
```

My solution was to make a Protocol class, which created an Up `Transform` and a Down `Transform`.

The Protocol constructor passes a reference (to itself) when constructing the Up and Down transforms.  The `_transform` method in each of the up and down transforms can then call `push` on itself, on the other `Transform`, or both as required.  Common state can be kept in the `Protocol` object.

Comment: +1, I think "up" and "down" are good names, because it can stand for abstraction level. You can pipe all the up channels of every layers, and also the down. But, I think it could be usefull to have a basic pipe2 and unpipe2 methods for doing both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A duplex stream is like your diagram B, at least for the user. A more complete view of a stream would be to include producer(source) with the consumer(user). See my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18339203/568109). Try not to think both read/write from a consumer point of view.

What you are doing is building a thin layer over the socket for protocol, so your design is correct :

```
                         -------+     +----------+     +------
                               r|---->|         r|---->|      
                         socket |     | protocol |     | rest of app
                               w|<----|         w|<----|      
                         -------+     +----------+     +------
```

You can use duplex or transform for the protocol part.

```
                 +---------+--------+---------+       +------------------+ 
                 | _write->|        |         |r      |   Transform  ->  |r
                 |-----------Duplex-----------|       +------------------+    
                 |         |        | <-_read |w      |   <- Transform   |w
                 +---------+--------+---------+       +------------------+
```

process being your protocol related processing on incoming/outgoing data using internal _read, _write. Or you can transform streams. You would pipe protocol to socket and socket to protocol .

Comment: The protocol needs to share state between the two transforms.  How is it best to do this?

Comment: You can set flags to represent state or store data within a stream.  See the [simpleprotocolv2](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_example_simpleprotocol_parser_v2) example. You do it with these `this._sawFirstCr = false;
  this._rawHeader = [];`

Comment: For your task it is best done with duplex as both streams can see the flags easily. For transforms you will have to set flags twice for both the streams.

Comment: My point is that there are two intimately connected transforms in the protocol.  A packet from the socket, may cause a packet to be sent to the socket and/or a packet to be sent to the app.  Likewise a packet from the app may cause a packet to be sent to the socket and/or a packet to be sent to the app.